# Replication from CouchDB to TouchDB

Tags: android, couchdb, replication, database-replication, touchdb

I could able to replicate .touchDB with CouchDB and sync data. But i could not able to replicate from CouchDB to touchDB.

Can any one please explain how to do that.

Thanks

Chinna

Answer (score 0):

TouchDB is basically an obsolete product.  It has been renamed and further enhanced under the name Couchbase Lite.  I suggest you download and integrate the new code and try from there.

Have you tried the GrocerySync sample application? It does replication to full couchdb servers.  I was able to use the Android version and work with a full couchbase server.

Comment: The Grocery explains and works sync data from TouchDB to CouchDB and not from CouchDB to TouchDB

Comment: There may be a firewall between the CouchDB server and the TouchDB client that prevents a push from the server to the client. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825154/how-do-i-push-from-a-couchdb-server-to-a-touchdb-client as to why pushing from the server is not a great idea.